# Prometheus OpenMetrics import not setting type info

Tags: prometheus

Running a local Prometheus (v2.45.2), I attempt to import some metrics from a production system for offline analysis and alert development. (Metrics extracted separately and OpenMetrics style file created from data).

Format of OpenMetrics import file (metrics.txt) as follows:

```
# TYPE http_inbound_duration_count counter
# HELP http_inbound_duration_count A metric descrition
http_inbound_duration_count{api="createBooking",httpCode="201"} 9 1708899600
http_inbound_duration_count{api="createBooking",httpCode="201"} 45 1708899900
....
# EOF
```

Imported into Prometheus using **promtool**:
`./promtool tsdb create-blocks-from openmetrics some/path/metrics.txt ./data`

This *appears* to import happily, and I get *some* results back when using the UI. However, using any functions like `increase` results in no results.

Using autocompletion in the UI, the metric appears to be missing type information:
[image]

When checking this with the REST api, it appears to confirm this:

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/targets/metadata?metric=http_inbound_duration_count
```

Results in: `{"status":"success","data":[]}`

What am I doing wrong?
Any help much appreciated

I was expecting to be able to use this and other metrics in the same way as on the production system.